# Were the terms "Dilscoop" and "Carrom ball" coined by Mahendra Mapagunaratne?

Tags: history, sport

[This web article](http://www.zimbio.com/Cricket/articles/eGtbd6abbXo/JOSEPHIAN+MAFIA) claims that the terms were coined by **Mahendra Mapagunaratne**.

> The neologism Josephian Mafia is thought to be coined by Mahendra
>   Mapagunaratne - a Sri Lankan cricket connoisseur based in Canada who
>   incidentally coined the terms **[Carrom Ball](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrom_ball)** for Ajantha Mendis' finger
>   flicking delivery and **[Dilscoop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilscoop)** for Tillekeratne Dilshan's unique back
>   scoop over the wicket keeper's head.

Can anyone please confirm this? Wikipedia articles on these two terms have no clues on who coined the terms.

Comment: Please link to the Wikipedia articles mentioned in your question.

Comment: I think this question should be migrated to english.SE, or,  at least, I believe it would be.

Comment: @coleopterist Dilscoop --> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilscoop

Carrom ball --> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrom_ball

Comment: @Carlo_R. I thought this belonged here because it's about a claim (not the word itself, but about the origin of it!)